# Import Eclipse C++ Workspace Into Visual Studio Code for Linux

Tags: eclipse, import, visual-studio-code, workspace

I have a workspace in Eclipse on Linux Mint. This project builds for and ARM platform device running Debian linux.

I am not an expert on this. We have a guru who set it all up for us. I am not sure which method the project uses to build the apps, but I do know all I have to do it right click the project in Eclipse and select build on any of the apps and they build.

I would like to use VS Code to develop this app. Is there any way to import the whole workspace into VS Code and have it actually build and debug on the target device?

If so can someone please give me the steps?

Comment: Have you found a way to import your project? I'd really like to do the same.

Comment: I have not. If someone can help us out I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I just clicked menu item File->Open Folder...
Then navigate to the parent folder of your workspace, which is actually your Eclipse workspace folder. Highlight it, then click the Select Folder button. Then it just loaded all my Source files in. I can't tell you how to convert to building your code, as I only did this to search files and hopefully find variable's definitions. And this worked! I didn't even need to do a full scan of my source files or anything (or maybe it did this automatically at some point). I just went to the definition-unknown variable's location I know about, highlighted it, and right-clicked and selected Go to definition, and it went and opened the file with its definition.